# Jexcelapi Getting the number of rows in one column

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I can find the number of rows in the excel document using 
sheet.getRows(); 
however the rows in my excel file are of different lengths, how could I get the number of rows in only 1 column. 
I've found 
[getting rows in file](http://www.coderanch.com/t/63874/open-source/number-rows-column-Excel-JXL) and
[List of methods in the library](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html)
but neither have the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. 
I got it by getting the array of cells and then count the length of the array.Where 'int row' is the row that you want to count.

```
..
workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(SheetPath));
    .. 
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);  //adjust depending on which sheet you need. 
//find out how many cells there are on this row.
Cell[] cellColumn = sheet.getRow(row);
int cellCount = cellColumn.length;
System.out.println("cells in col: " + cellCount);
```

Here is extra api:
http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/

Let me know if you need additional clarification